# Extract nodes from json based on user input preserveing a portion of the higher level object as well

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, glom

need to extract object from the given json based on the node chain passed by user and neglect those which are not in
user input, then create a new json object

my master json is :

```
{
"menustructure": 
[
        {
         "node":"Admin",
         "path":"admin",
            "child":[
                    {
                        "id": "resouce0",
                        "node": "Admin.resouce0",
                        "path":"resouce0",
                        "rank":0,
                        "child":[
                             {   
                                "id": "res_child",
                                "node": "Admin.resouce0.res_child",
                                "path":"res_child",
                                "rank":1
                             },
                             {   
                                "id": "res_child2",
                                "node": "Admin.resouce0.res_child2",
                                "path":"res_child",
                                "rank":1
                             }
                                ]
                     },
                    {
                        "id": "resouce1",
                        "node": "Admin.resouce1",
                        "path":"resouce1",
                        "rank":1
                     },
                
                    {
                        "id": "resouce2",
                        "node":"Admin.resouce2",
                        "path": "oath",
                        "rank":2
                    }
                   ]
        },
        {
            "node":"Workspace",
            "path": "wsp",
            "child":[{
                    "id":"system1",
                    "node": "Workspace.system1",
                    "path":"sys1",
                    "child":[{
                           "id": "child1",
                           "node": "Workspace.system1.child1",
                           "path":"ch1"
                
                        }]
                
                },
                {   
                    "id":"system2",
                    "node": "Workspace.system2",
                    "path":"sys2"
                }
            ]
        }]}
```

for example if user pass `['Admin.resource1', 'Workspace']` so expeceted ouput json will be
**Note**    '.' in element of user inputted list means that node have child nodes and new json will be having all those child node details including parent node details.

```
{
    "menustructure": 
    [
            {
             "node":"Admin",
             "path":"admin",
                "child":[
                        {   "id": "resouce1",
                            "node": "Admin.resouce1",
                            "path":"resouce1",
                            "rank":1
                         }
                       ]
            },
            {
                "node":"Workspace",
                "path": "wsp",
                "child":[{
                        "id": "system1",
                        "node": "Workspace.system1",
                        "path":"sys1"
                         "child":[{
                           "id": "child1",
                           "node": "Workspace.system1.child1",
                           "path":"ch1"
                    
                    },
                    {   "id": "system2",
                        "node": "Workspace.system2",
                        "path":"sys2"
                    }
                ]
            }

        
    ]
}
```

or another example is : `['Admin.resouce2', 'workspace.system1']` then expected json will be:

```
{
    "menustructure": 
    [
            {
             "node":"Admin",
             "path":"admin",
                "child":[
                        
                        {"id": "resouce2","node":"Admin.resouce2",
                            "path": "oath",
                            "rank":2
                        }
                       ]
            },
            {
                "node":"Workspace",
                "path": "wsp",
                "child":[{
                        "id": "system1",
                        "node": "Workspace.system1",
                        "path":"sys1"
                        "child":[{
                           "id": "child1",
                           "node": "Workspace.system1.child1",
                           "path":"ch1"
                    
                    }
                ]
            }
    ]
}
```

or if only single node passed `['Admin']` then output json will be:

```
{
    "menustructure": 
    [
            {
             "node":"Admin",
             "path":"admin",
                "child":[
                        {
                            "id": "resouce1",
                            "node": "Admin.resouce1",
                            "path":"resouce1",
                            "rank":1
                         },
                    
                        {"id": "resouce2","node":"Admin.resouce2",
                            "path": "oath",
                            "rank":2
                        }
                       ]
            }   
    ]
}
```

Code I tried is working for one level of child:

```
master = json.loads(m)
menustruct = []
test_master = master['menustructure']
temp_json = test_master
nde = ['Admin.resouce1', 'Admin.resouce0', 'Workspace.system2']
temp_data = master['menustructure']
#print(temp_data)
final_data = []
parent_node = []
for m in nde:
    items = copy.deepcopy(temp_data)
    if "." in m:
        menu_series = m.split(".")
        for item in items:
            if item['node'] == menu_series[0]:
                item_child_nodes = item['child']
                child = None
                for node in item_child_nodes:
                    if node['id'] != menu_series[1]:
                        item_child_nodes.remove(node)
                    else:
                        child = node

                if menu_series[0] in parent_node:
                    for i in final_data:
                        if i['node'] == menu_series[0]:
                            i['child'].append(child)
                else:
                    final_data.append(item)
                #print(item_child_nodes)
        parent_node.append(menu_series[0])

    else:
        for item in items:
            if item['node'] == m:
                final_data.append(item)
t = {}
t['menustructure'] = final_data
print(t)
```

but not getting how to handle multiple child level for example

```
{master -> child -> child} or {master -> child -> child -> child}
```

multilevel child is present in Workspace.system1
If child parent already exist then child should get appended into parent node in resulting json

I tried Glom lib but it's not working as intended.
Any help on how to achieve multi level child problem.

Comment: In your example, using the "master json", I don't know if you correctly copy-pasted it on SO, but it's riddled with missing delimiters/commas, and brackets. I want to make a solution, but I would appreciate if you could fix this first (so it works correctly with `json.loads`)

Comment: @NordineLotfi I have updated master json,, sorry for mistake

Comment: "I tried Glom lib but it's not working as intended." We can only possibly help with that if you **show how** you tried using the library, **explain what happened**, and make sure it is clear **why that result is wrong** (i.e. what "not working as intended" **means**).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my solution. The idea is to traverse the structure recursively and remove nodes that don't match user input. The algorithm does not mutate the input data, but creates a shallow copy of the subtree only when the `child` attribute is changed.

```py
def extract(data, query):
    return {
        "menustructure": extract_nodes(
            data["menustructure"], [x.split(".") for x in query]
        )
    }


def matches(name, query):
    name = name.split(".")
    for q in query:
        size = min(len(q), len(name))
        if name[:size] == q[:size]:
            return True

    return False


def extract_nodes(data, query):
    if isinstance(data, list):
        data = [
            extract_nodes(x, query)
            for x in data
            if matches(x["node"], query)
        ]
        return [x for x in data if x is not None]

    if isinstance(data, dict) and matches(data["node"], query):
        if "child" in data:
            children = extract_nodes(data["child"], query)
            if len(children) != len(data["child"]):
                data = data.copy()  # copy-on-write
                data["child"] = children
            if not data["child"]:
                return None
        return data
```

Usage:

```py
import json
data = json.loads(m)
result = extract(data, ["Admin.resouce1", "Workspace.system1"])
print(json.dumps(result, indent=4))


result = extract(data, ["Admin.resouce0.res_child"])
print(json.dumps(result, indent=4))
```

Comment: this code is working fine for 1 level of child eg "Admin.resouce1", but not working for sub-child of child eg: 'Admin.resouce0.res_child'.
Code output for it filters out the level 1 child but returns all subchild of  resouce0 instead of returning only res_child. any idea on how to apply same logic for subchild.

Comment: Improved matching logic. Code returned both res_child and res_child2 because they have the same prefix. Now it only returns `res_child` for `Admin.resouce0.res_child`